# Scrape name of HTML attribute rvest

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest

I am trying to scrape a job postings website with rvest (https://www.stepstone.de/5/ergebnisliste.html?stf=freeText&ns=1&qs=%5B%5D&companyID=0&cityID=0&sourceOfTheSearchField=homepagemex%3Ageneral&searchOrigin=Homepage_top-search&ke=building+information+modeliing&ws=&ra=30).

I want to extract the date the job posting has been created (2020-12-07T02:13:28+01:00) which can be found here:

```
<time class="" datetime="2020-12-07T02:13:28+01:00" timeago-id="17">vor 1 Woche</time>
```

However, I only manage to get how many days ago the job posting has been created, e.g. vor 1 Woche (1 week ago). My code looks as follows:

```
url = "https://www.stepstone.de/5/ergebnisliste.html?stf=freeText&ns=1&qs=%5B%5D&companyID=0&cityID=0&sourceOfTheSearchField=homepagemex%3Ageneral&searchOrigin=Homepage_top-search&ke=building+information+modeliing&ws=&ra=30"
read_html(url) %>%
  html_nodes('time') %>% 
  html_text()
```

Happy about any help! Thank you!

Comment: These attributes don't exist in the raw html. They are added dynamically in your browser from a deeply-nested json string on the same page using javascript. It would not be impossible to retrieve the time stamps, but it would take a lot of parsing to extract them. You may be better going fown the RSelenium route here

Answer (score 0):

First, "datetime" is an attribute, so you'll want to try exploiting html_attr or html_attrs.

Second, more importantly, I'm not seeing datetime in any of your nodes (only class). Are you sure that's an attribute on this website for all time nodes?

```
> library(rvest)
> 
> url = "https://www.stepstone.de/5/ergebnisliste.html?stf=freeText&ns=1&qs=%5B%5D&companyID=0&cityID=0&sourceOfTheSearchField=homepagemex%3Ageneral&searchOrigin=Homepage_top-search&ke=building+information+modeliing&ws=&ra=30"
> test = read_html(url) %>%
+   html_nodes('time')
> 
> test
{xml_nodeset (25)}
 [1] <time class="">vor 1 Woche</time>
 [2] <time class="">vor 1 Woche</time>
 [3] <time class="">vor 2 Tagen</time>
 [4] <time class="">vor 1 Woche</time>
 [5] <time class="">vor 6 Tagen</time>
 [6] <time class="">vor 12 Stunden</time>
 [7] <time class="">vor 18 Stunden</time>
 [8] <time class="">vor 23 Stunden</time>
 [9] <time class="">vor 1 Woche</time>
[10] <time class="">vor 1 Tag</time>
[11] <time class="">vor 2 Tagen</time>
[12] <time class="">vor 1 Tag</time>
[13] <time class="">vor 6 Tagen</time>
[14] <time class="">vor 2 Tagen</time>
[15] <time class="">vor 2 Tagen</time>
[16] <time class="">vor 2 Tagen</time>
[17] <time class="">vor 2 Tagen</time>
[18] <time class="">vor 6 Tagen</time>
[19] <time class="">vor 1 Woche</time>
[20] <time class="">vor 1 Woche</time>
```